# How to store timestamps in array?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, numpy, timestamp

I need to import some series of measurements of several users from an excel file . For further calculation I also need the timestamp. I was thinking to store it in an array, but it's not working.

```
for n in range(len(users)):
    sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name=users[n],name_columns_by_row=0)
    sheet = sheet.to_array()
    data_meas = np.array(sheet)
    data_no_time=(data_meas[2:,2:].astype(np.float))
    #print(data_meas)

    # get timestamps 
    for row in range(len(data_meas)-2):
        input_time = data_meas[row+2,1]
        input_date = data_meas[row+2,0]

        times =datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        datarr = np.array(times, 'datetime64[us]')
```

Does anybody know how to handle this?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full traceback. "It does not work" is no a helpful error description.

Comment: datarr stores only one value and not all the timestamps from the list. 
I would like to have one array with all the timestamps and that I can call the timestamps by index.

Comment: this is the error when i call datarr[0] :  IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Add the clarifying information to your post.  It's more readable there than in comments.

Comment: `times` is a single value, a scalar. `datarr` is then a 0d array.  You shouldn't need to index it.